# How to retrieve only one result with preg_grep or reset numeric keys when there are multiple matches?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, rest

I am working on a code that retrieves image links from a wordpress site using the REST API and curl.

My code therefore retrieves the image links provided by the json generated by curl then I retrieve the basename of each link to split them in order to compare each term
with the title of the current wordpress article.

If any of the terms in the title are also found in the name of one or more images, preg_grep displays the results.

The problem is that I would like to retrieve a single result (The first key for example), it doesn't matter which one.

I tried with preg_match but my regex knowledge is limited, do you have any solutions to share?

**
PS: The result of preg_match creates a multi-dimensional array, and I would only want one so I could manage and hope to get a single result in my var_dump.**

**
here's the result:**

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "buzz"
}

array(1) {
  [3]=>
  string(10) "actualites"
}
```

**Here is my shortcut code:**

`

```
$title = get_the_title(); 
        $regex = array('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '/\s/');
        $repl  = array('', '-');
        $slug = preg_replace($regex, $repl, $title);
                            
        $res_title = explode('-', $slug);

        $path = array(
            'https://ivredevi.fr/wp-json/wp/v2/media?per_page=100&page=1',
        );

        $node_count = count($path);
        
        $curl_arr = array();
        $master = curl_multi_init();
        
        for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
        {
            $url =$path[$i];
            $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
        }
        
        do {
            curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
        } while($running > 0);

        for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
        {
            $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
            $img = json_decode($results, true);
        
            $arr_col = array_column($img, 'source_url');

                $new_array = [];
                foreach ($arr_col as $ncol) {
                    $cnt = basename($ncol, '.jpg');
                    $names = explode('-', $cnt);
        
                    foreach ($res_title as $value) {
        
                        $pattern = "/$value/i";
                    
                        $results = preg_grep($pattern, $names);

                        $sk = [];
        
                        if($results){

                            var_dump($results);

                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            
        
        }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: We probably don't need to see all of this wordpress and curl code.  Please provide a static input array of data (as text from `var_export()`), then show us how it should be processed and what your exact desired result is from your sample data.  As with your earlier (closed and deleted) question we need to better understand your variables -- it is strange for a variable holding a regex pattern to be named `$arr`. `$exp` is a strange name for an array.

Comment: If you want to push data into a flat result array, do not use `array_merge_recursive()`, but `array_push($new_array, ...preg_grep("/$ats/i", $exp));`

Comment: I recommend making fewer, longer replacements by adding the `+` quantifier so that `array('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '/\s/')` becomes `array('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]+/u', '/\s+/')`

Comment: @micmackus I took note of your recommendations for more clarity in the code. Thanks for your help. Yes i already tried array_merge_recursive() but it doesn't work.

Comment: We cannot confidently help you until you provide an input array. I am assuming the "here's the result" data is from `var_dump($results)` -- but we can't use the end result, we need the data from the start.  We need to know what data is in all of these variables.  We are not going to be making any curl calls to better understand your question. Please boil down your question further.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing with `$kop`, but it will pretty much always be `true`. [shuffle()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) modifies by reference.  Usually developers do not assign its return value to a variable.  Please [edit] your question to include a multidimensional array containing multiple sets if `$arr_col` data.